# How could I tell git diff-index show only files with changed permissions?

Tags: git, file-permissions

Is there native ability in git to diff file permissions only?

I use something like `git diff-index HEAD | cut -d ' ' -f '1 2 5 6'`, but I want to see files with permissions changes only.